# NextJS dynamic route work on first load, but fails on refresh

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, next.js

I have a NextJS app that has a dynamic route `posts/[id].js` When the page loads, everything is fine. When I refresh, the dynamic data is undefined resulting in:

> Server Error
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

```
export default function Post({ post }) {
    return (
        <Layout>
            <Head>
                <title>{post.title}</title>
            </Head>
            <h1 className={utilStyles.headingXl}>{post.title}</h1>
            <br />
            <p className={utilStyles.lightText}>{post.body}</p>
            <br />
            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.contentHtml }} />
        </Layout>
    );
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
    console.log('params :', params);
    // params.id === slug
    const { db } = await connectToDatabase();
    const post = await db.collection('posts').findOne({ slug: params.id });

    return {
        props: {
            post: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(post))
        }
    };
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
    const { db } = await connectToDatabase();
    const posts = await db
        .collection('posts')
        .find({})
        .sort({ metacritic: -1 })
        .limit(20)
        .toArray();

    const paths = posts.map((post) => `/posts/${post.id}`);

    return {
        paths,
        fallback: true
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what it was. User error! of course... Lazy coding leads to stupid errors.

You'll notice in the code I posted there is a comment `params.id === slug` because I was originally using the documents id to get things going then, I moved to slugs. and made that comment to remind myself later... I forgot.

My get static paths was still referencing the id. Doh!